# Python VW Hyperopt

Tags: python, vowpalwabbit, hyperopt

I am trying to find the hyperparameters of my VW model using VW Hyperopt https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-hyperopt.py

But after installing all the necessary packages i'm still getting this error :

```
  2018-12-06 13:41:03,991 INFO     [hyperopt.fmin/fmin:139]: job exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./vw-hyperopt.py", line 378, in <module>
        main()
      File "./vw-hyperopt.py", line 372, in main
        h.hyperopt_search()
      File "./vw-hyperopt.py", line 320, in hyperopt_search
        best_params = fmin(objective, space=self.space, trials=self.trials, algo=algo, max_evals=self.max_evals)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 367, in fmin
        return_argmin=return_argmin,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 635, in fmin
        return_argmin=return_argmin)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 385, in fmin
        rval.exhaust()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 244, in exhaust
        self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.asynchronous)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 218, in run
        self.serial_evaluate()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 137, in serial_evaluate
        result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 840, in evaluate
        rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
      File "./vw-hyperopt.py", line 294, in objective
        self.fit_vw()
      File "./vw-hyperopt.py", line 234, in fit_vw
        subprocess.call(shlex.split(self.train_command))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
        return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any leads on how to get rid of this error would be really helpful. I am using Python2